# Doctrine query building select MAX

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.1

I would like to select everything + MAX value and receive only rows having max values.

```
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');
    $query->where('s.challenge = :challenge')->setParameter('challenge', $challenge);
    $query->groupBy('s.score');
    $query->getQuery();

    return $query->select('s.*, MAX(s.score) AS max_score')->getQuery()->getResult();
```

How could I achieve this in doctrine? I am getting an error that * property is not found. I have tried to select them all one by one but no luck either.

Goal is to achieve something like this

```
SELECT user, challenge, whateverelse, MAX(score) FROM users_scores_table GROUP BY user_id
```

Please help ;)

Comment: DQL =/= SQL , not sure what you are trying to do here. select(' s , ... ) should be enough.

Comment: This will select me only max_score and not my entire entity.. I am trying to get all unique highest scores for users.

Comment: Just do select('s, MAX(s.score)') like @mpm suggested.

Comment: This seem to work fine(ish), thnkas guys, but I am receiving array within array (object, max value) but intention is to receive objects only...

Comment: This is still not right... 'I would like to select everything + MAX value and receive only rows having max values.' so even though i can extract max score and object.. the object is 'random' not the one with highest score... so seems like i need to be using distinct but distinct does not seem to work for me

Answer (score 34):

It's too late, but I write this for the records.

You can use "as HIDDEN" in SELECT statements to remove a field of the final result, this way you can use it for ordering or grouping without modifying result fields.

In your example:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');
$query->select('s, MAX(s.score) AS HIDDEN max_score');
$query->where('s.challenge = :challenge')->setParameter('challenge', $challenge);
$query->groupBy('s.user');
$query->setMaxResults($limit);
$query->orderBy('max_score', 'DESC');
```

Answer (score 30):

Here is a final working query

```
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');
    $query->select('s, MAX(s.score) AS max_score');
    $query->where('s.challenge = :challenge')->setParameter('challenge', $challenge);
    $query->groupBy('s.user');
    $query->setMaxResults($limit);
    $query->orderBy('max_score', 'DESC');

    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Please mark it as an answer, also where do you get $limit?